# What is the naming convention for ASP.NET Core projects?

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP.Net Core the convention for projects seems to be to put the ASP.Net Core projects inside a `src\` folder, and the test projects inside a `test\` folder.

What other conventions are there, ie. where should a web (front-end only) project be located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The honest answer to this is "it depends." The `src` and `test` folders at the root are a common structure seen in code repositories today.

Here are some common root folders and what they may contain:

- test - Unit tests, UI tests, Integration tests, etc.
- src - Source code projects
- tools - Strong-name files and/or 3rd party tools that may be used to help tests or builds
- build - Scripts to perform various builds on the project
- docs - Documentation files for the project

> How would you organize a web (front-end only) project inside an ASP.NET Core directory structure?

The only advice I can give without knowing your project, and the people interacting with it, is to keep it simple. I haven't found a need to add more root folders beyond what's seen above.

Keep in mind that there are certain folders that a default project template is going to use:

- By default, Grunt is set up to look in the `css`, `js`, and `lib` folders under wwwroot for its bundling process.
- Bower (also with the default template) will install packages into the `lib` folder under `wwwroot`.
- MVC looks through the `Views` folder for view templates.